# Is synchrotron radiation considered incandescent?

Tags: visible-light, thermal-radiation, synchrotron-radiation

Synchrotron radiation is produced via the acceleration of charged particles, much like incandescence.
However, all information I've seen state that incandescent light is produced exclusively from the thermal motion of the charges.

Is there therefore a better term to describe the light produced via synchrotrons?
Thanks!

Comment: We call it "synchrotron radiation". No. Really.

Comment: Incandescence is incandescence. It is a definition. "Emitting light as a result of being heated.". This is not what synchrotron radiation is, it is as dmckee states; synchrotron radiation...

Comment: Is there a particular reason I received a negative vote? Did I disobey site protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchrotron radiation is a high energy phenomenon. It is a form of [bremsstrahlung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung), this being the electromagnetic radiation produced by the deceleration of a charged particle when deflected by another charged particle, typically an electron by an atomic nucleus.

[Synchrotron radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) is produced in the deceleration of a charged particle in a magnetic field, usually the field accelerating  and controling the beams in accelerators. The difference to bremsstrahlung lies in  that it is an interaction with the macroscopic field and not the field of  individual atoms.

Comment: So would referring to it as incandescent be incorrect? I think VCAA themselves (an education authority in Victoria, Australia) referred to it as being incandescent :|

Comment: It depends on your definition of "incandescent". If you look at the picture in the synchrotron link it looks as if it is a furnace light. In truth it is not,because it is directional whereas incandescence comes from random atomic processes.